# How do I plot a triangle in three dimensions?

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry

I would like to draw different triangles by using MATLAB shown in the figure below. Suppose that I have 3 vectors `V1=[1 1 1]`, `V2=[-1 1 1]`, `v3=[-2 -2 -2]`.

How can I draw triangle with these vectors in 3D?

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Can't open the link. Do you need something like triangulation() and triplot()?

Comment: Thanks for your interest https://www.researchgate.net/post/Plot_a_triagnle_in_three_dimension_by_using_matlab

Comment: @Amir, you should precise that your `v1`, `v2` and `v3` represent _coordinates_ of points (and not vectors in the mathematical term). The fact that you call them "vector" (which is correct as a Matlab term) but also named them `v...` can be confusing if someone reads you too literally.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `plot3()` like this:

```
v1=[1 1 1]; v2=[-1 1 1]; v3=[-2 -2 -2];

triangle = [v1(:), v2(:), v3(:), v1(:)];
plot3(triangle(1, :), triangle(2, :), triangle(3, :))

xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
```

This is the output:

[image]

---

**Edit:**

This is in order to plot axis:

```
val = 5; %// Max value of axis
axX = [0 0 0; val 0 0];
axY = [0 0 0; 0 val 0];
axZ = [0 0 0; 0 0 val];
plot3(axX(:, 1), axX(:, 2), axX(:, 3), 'k');
plot3(axY(:, 1), axY(:, 2), axY(:, 3), 'k');
plot3(axZ(:, 1), axZ(:, 2), axZ(:, 3), 'k');
text(val, 0, 0, 'x')
text(0, val, 0, 'y')
text(0, 0, val, 'z')
view(3)
```

[image]

In addition you can make the plot look like your reference image, adding these commands to above code:

```
set(gca,'xtick',[], 'xcolor', 'w')
set(gca,'ytick',[], 'ycolor', 'w', 'YDir','reverse')
set(gca,'ztick',[], 'zcolor', 'w')
view(45, 30)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Is it possible to make x and y axis as depicted like in first figure ?

Comment: @Amir - I don't think so, because this is the way how matlab plots. However, the best thing that you could plots axis on the same figure additionally, would be my naive suggestion. See my edit.